# "threading" vs "thread" packages in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, anaconda, python-multithreading

What is difference between "threading" and "thread" packages in anaconda? Which one to install, both commands have been used in multi threading python projects, so which package should I use for my eye detection project?(Some sites say threading comes with anaconda..no need to install)
So how to proceed installing these packages in anaconda prompt?

Answer (score 1):

`thread` is built-in module provides primitive operations to write multi-threaded programs. where as `threading` module provides a more convenient interface (which is similar to Java threading model).

So you should use `threading` in your project

And they are built-in you can start using them simply by

```
import threading
import thread
```

If you want help on modules you can always check in python interpreter by `dir(modulename)`

like this

```
import threading
dir(threading)
```